# IntelliJ IDEA plugin install fails with read timeout

Tags: intellij-idea, proxy, timeout

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 Utlimate Edition behind a corporate proxy (which apparently does content analysis).

Although plugin management (install, update) usually works, I had a problem installing the KS Explorer plugin recently. After some background processing (~100 seconds), I get a popup with the following content:

> **Plugin Installation**
>
> Plugin "KS-Explorer" was not installed: Cannot download 'htps://plugins.jetbrains.com/pluginManager/?uuid=2707211d7cdae70-bfb2-4189-b643-d6ca28a16ac4&id=co.anbora.labs.kse&build=IU-213.7172.25': Read timed out

The same download URL works in a browser: after some waiting, it downloads an 8MB zip file (which I could probably use for manual installation).

The reason for the read timeout is probably the corporate proxy: it has to analyse the zip file for malicious content before letting the bytes pass through to my desktop - and in this case, the analyis takes a bit longer than usual.

The question is: how do I set the read timeout value used by the plugin download process?

Answer (score 2):

I did not find any official reference documentation on how to set read and connection timeouts. My main source of information is a similar plugin management issue posted on the JetBrains community support site:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005819880-Can-t-find-any-plugin-at-marketplace

Credits go to [Andrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2000323).

It turns out IDEA has properties for setting connection and read timeout:

```
idea.connection.timeout=...
idea.read.timeout=...
```

I'd guess values are representing milliseconds. The problem mentioned in the question above was solved by setting the read timeout value to 200000. YMMV

To fix read timeouts occuring while installing / upgrading plugins, one should use either:

**Help | Edit Custom Properties...**

or

**Help | Edit Custom VM Options...**